# Creating an openshift cluster aws failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, ansible, openshift

```
Hosts: .compute.internal, compute.internal
Play: OpenShift Health Checks
Task: Run health checks (install) - EL
Message: One or more checks failed
Details: check "docker_image_availability":
One or more required container images are not available:
docker.io/cockpit/kubernetes:latest,
docker.io/openshift/origin-deployer:v3.11,
docker.io/openshift/origin-docker-registry:v3.11,
docker.io/openshift/origin-haproxy-router:v3.11,
docker.io/openshift/origin-pod:v3.11
Checked with: skopeo inspect [--tls-verify=false] [--creds=<user>:<pass>] docker://<registry>/<image>


2. Hosts: .compute.internal
Play: OpenShift Health Checks
Task: Run health checks (install) - EL
Message: One or more checks failed
Details: check "docker_image_availability":
One or more required container images are not available:
docker.io/cockkubernetes:latest,
docker.io/openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11,
docker.io/openshift/origin-deployer:v3.11,
docker.io/openshift/origin-docker-registry:v3.11,
docker.io/openshift/origin-haproxy-router:v3.11,
docker.io/openshift/origin-pod:v3.11,
quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.2.22
Checked with: skopeo inspect [--tls-verify=false] [--creds=<user>:<pass>] docker://<registry>/<image> ``
```

I'm getting this error while trying to create an openshift cluster on aws .but the images are present .Please help?